# Constant GameObject rotation in a specific angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in unity that I want to rotate with a specific angle of 22.5 degrees on the z-axis and the rotation should NOT be smooth, it's NOT meant to be smooth, the object should have a speed variable and bool variable that toggles the rotation of the object.

I tried an approach in which I created a variable called "delayBetweenRotation" and used time in unity to check if the elapsed time is great than this variable, and if that's true then the object will add 22.5 degrees to its rotation, this approach worked fine but it sometimes has a problem that when we set the bool to false then it stops rotating after rotating another 22.5 degrees.

Comment: You need to provide a code sample. It looks like some logical error in the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not a technical problem, but requires some effort and thought to implement it. Anyway, the following code will solve your problem.

```cs
public bool phase = true;

public float delayBetweenTime = 1f;
private float currentTime;
void Update()
{

    currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (currentTime >= delayBetweenTime) // after 1 sec for example, current timer will be reset try to rotate
    {
        currentTime = 0f;
        
        if (phase) // when phase is enabled!
        {   
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 22.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this exact approach, and I also tried your code but this problem still persists, I believe it happens because when we set the bool to false when the object is just about to rotate, but I am disabling the script when the bool is false (from other object), any help is much appritiated

Comment: It sounds like the object rotation occurs before the bool can be set to false within the same frame. You should consider changing the script execution order in Unity, or put the rotation logic in LateUpdate.

Comment: I tried using LateUpdate, but its still not fixed

Comment: You'll have to post some code then.

Comment: Sure here is the code - (I control the "playerInside" variable from another script

    void LateUpdate()
    {

        currentTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (currentTime >= delayBetweenRotation) timer will be reset try to rotate
        {
            currentTime = 0f;

            if (playerInside) // when phase is enabled!
            {
                transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotAngle);
                barrelSpriteManager.UpdateBarrelSprite();
            }
        }
    }